# GitHub flavored markdown code syntax highlighting forcing type

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Take this simple code markdown:

````
```cs
var x = new Locked<Rec>(new ("John", 35)); 
```
````

This renders in GitHub readme like this:

[image]

I now just add a definition:

````
```cs
record Rec(string Name, int Age);
var x= new Locked<Rec>(new ("John", 35)); 
```
````

and it now renders like this:

[image]

As you can see the type `Locked` and the `new` are for some reason no longer coloured purple. Why is this and how can I get around it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code does the same thing.

I'm not a C# developer, but [the examples I found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) all instantiate the record inside `Main`:

````markdown
```cs
record Rec(string Name, int Age);

public static void Main()
{
    var x = new Locked<Rec>(new ("John", 35)); 
}
```
````

This seems to get both VSCode and GitHub to highlight syntax as you expect:

[image: GitHub rendering with syntax highlighting]

It works even better if you declare the record inside `Main` as well:

[image: GitHub rendering with syntax highlighting]